# Find shortest distance between two functions

Tags: functions

The problem is to find the shortest distance for given functions: y=x^2+7/2 and y=ln(x) without using `Minimize`.

Does anyone have any idea how to approach this problem? I'm very new to mathematica, so would be much appreciated if someone could help!

Comment: Do you mean the shortest distance between their graphs?

Answer (score 10):

Assuming that you mean the shortest distance between their graphs, the following does the job.

```
NMinimize[{Sqrt[(y1 - y2)^2 + (x1 - x2)^2], y1 == x1^2 + 7/2 && x2 == Exp[y2] && x2 > 0}, {x1, x2, y1, y2}]
```

> `{3.35325, {x1 -> 0.269081, x2 -> 1.85817, y1 -> 3.5724,  y2 -> 0.619594}}`

Illustration

```
Plot[{x^2 + 7/2, Log[x]}, {x, 0.1, 6}, 
 Epilog -> 
  Line[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}} /.
 {x1 -> 0.269081, x2 -> 1.85817, y1 -> 3.5724, y2 -> 0.619594}]
 , AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {-1, 5}}
 , PlotLegends -> {"x^2+7/2", "Log[x]"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes exactly, I want the shortest distance between their graphs. Thank you for the answer!

Also, is there a way to solve this without using Minimize?

Comment: @Lentato:  I don't think so: "shortest distance" needs  minimization.

Comment: @Lentato: In principle you could use a combination of `Grad` and `Solve`/`NSolve` to tell Mathematica to solve the equations $\partial f/\partial x_1 = 0$ and $\partial f/\partial x_2 = 0$, where $f$ is the distance between the points $(x_1, f_1(x_1))$ and $(x_2, f(x_2))$.  But that's one of the algorithms that Mathematica tries when you invoke `Minimize`/`NMinimize` anyhow.

Comment: The constraint `x2 > 0` is not needed.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you mean by "shortest distance" the x value and y values where both functions differ by a minimal amount. In this case the distance is given by the difference of the two function. To get the corresponding x/y values you may minimize this difference:

```
f[x_] = x^2 + 7/2 - (Log[x]);
Minimize[f[x], x]
```

[image]

where the first value is the difference and the second the corresponding x value.

Answer (score 3):

We consider the square of the distance of the two graphics `{u,u^2+7/2}` and `{v,Log[v]}` which we denote `d2` and calculate  its critical point and Hessian.

```
f[x_] = x^2 + 7/2;
g[x_] = Log[x];
d2[u_, v_] = # . # &@Subtract[{u, u^2 + 7/2}, {v, Log[v]}];
sol = Solve[{D[d2[u, v], u] == 0, D[d2[u, v], v] == 0}, {u, v}, Reals,
    Method -> Reduce];
D[d2[u, v], {{u, v}, 2}] /. sol[[1]] // PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ

Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, 2.5}, 
 Epilog -> ({Line[{{u, f[u]}, {v, g[v]}}], AbsolutePointSize[10], Red,
      Point[{u, f[u]}], Point[{v, g[v]}]} /. sol[[1]]), 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {-1, 5}}]
d2[u, v] /. sol[[1]] //FullSimplify
%//Sqrt//N
```

> `True`

[image]

> `3.35325`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's an iterative method that I thought was cute:

```
r1 = ImplicitRegion[y == x^2 + 7/2, {x, y}];
r2 = ImplicitRegion[y == Log[x], {x, y}];

dist = FixedPoint[
    Apply@Function[
      {r1, r2, p1, p2},
      {r2, r1, p2, RegionNearest[r1, Rationalize[N[p2], 0]]}
      ],
    {r1, r2, {1., 1.}, {1.1, 1.1}},
    50, (* max iterations *)
    SameTest -> Function[
      {l1, l2},
      Norm[l1[[3 ;;]] - Reverse@l2[[3 ;;]], "Frobenius"]/
       Norm[l2[[3 ;;]], "Frobenius"] < 1*^-8]
    ][[3 ;;]];

EuclideanDistance @@ dist // N
(*  3.35325  *)

Plot[{x^2 + 7/2, Log[x]}, {x, -1, 4},
 Epilog -> {Line@dist}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 PlotRange -> {-1, 5}]
```

[image]

Because of the quadratic nature of an ordinary optimum, the best precision one can get in general is half machine precision or about `10^-8`.